# org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to model.UserPrincipal

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, userprincipal

I'm working with oauth2login in spring security. The redirection to the provider (facebook or google) was made with success but I'm getting the error : **org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to model.UserPrincipal**, in this line of code

`UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();`
My UserPrincipal class is like this :

```
public class UserPrincipal implements OAuth2User, OidcUser, UserDetails {
    
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    private Map<String, Object> claims;
    private OidcUserInfo oidcUserInfo;
    private OidcIdToken oidcIdToken;
...
}
```

How can I resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Have You Override methods in UserPrincipal class that implements OAuth2User, UserDetails.

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
```